# Get next page in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I get the **next page object** in jQuery Mobile?

Have tried this:

```
var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
```

and this:

```
var nextpage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').next('[data-role="page"]');
```

Non of them works. Have of course tried to read documentation but can't figure out how to do.

I'm having jQuery Mobile version 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).next('[data-role="page"]').prop("id");
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/MbEWBe)**

API Docs: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage